# laravel - make a filter with relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-filters

I have a product table with relations: `specValues`

In my product model:

```php
public function specValues(){
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\SpecValue', 'specvalued');
}
```

In my `specValues` in have:

```php
class SpecValue extends Model
{
  use Cachable;

    protected $table = 'specvalued';
    protected $fillable = ['field_id', 'value', 'value_desc', 'link', 
                           'specvalued_id', 'specvalued_type'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function specvalued()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function field()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\SpecField','field_id');
    }
}
```

Now, I whant to make a filter and multi filter for the products list:
with the `specvalued()` (from the `specvalued` table) I get the name (or id)
and with the "value" fild" from the `specvalued` table.

The `specValues` with product looks like this: (I have a lot like that but with a different `specvalued_id` and `value`, and I want a make a filter with that.

```php
#attributes: array:8 [▼
            "id" => 354327
            "field_id" => 4
            "specvalued_id" => 27535 //(name = year)
            "specvalued_type" => "Model\Product"
            "value" => "2017"
            "value_desc" => null
            "link" => null
            "created_at" => "2017-09-03 10:12:30"
          ]
```

And I try to make something like that to get a products with `spespic` value from `specValues` table  after filter:

```php
$products = $category->products()->with('specValues')->
where ????
orderBy('position')->paginate(20);
```

How do I the where options with my info?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code.

This code is used with relationship and `$specidsarr` is out side variable used in with condition in with relationship as well as `$q` is working with all outside conditions.

```
$products = $category->products()->with(['specValues' => 
    function($q) use($specidsarr) {
        $q->whereIn('feild', $specidsarr);
    }
]);
```

Comment: im sorry but i didnt success, Can not figure out how to change it to my fields

Comment: Can you try with relationship, **`with('specValues')`** instead of **`with(['specValues' => function($query) {$query->where("fld", "id");}])`**

Comment: i send u a msg on face/book

Comment: its didnt work :/ i make like this:   $products = $category->products()->with(['specValues' => function($query) {
      $query->where('specvalued_id','27535')->where("value", "2017");
    }]); and i get the count like without the filter :/

Comment: just change inside query, like this, 
`$query->where('specvalued_id','27535')->orwhere("value", "2017");`